# aspnet core azure function not starting with string array in local.settings.json

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-functions

I'm creating an Azure Function project on Visual Studio 2017,

the application was working well until I add a `string array` to `local.settings.json`

workinging json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "RequestTimeout": "600000"
  }
}
```

[image]

Not working json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "RequestTimeout": "600000",
    "Urls": [
      "https://url1.com.br/",
      "https://url2.com.br"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

What should I have to do to add this string array to the config file?

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't... `local.settings.json` is just one method to set configuration; others are with environment variables and Application settings in the portal. Those methods only allow strings as values.

Try encoding your array inside a string, and then deserialize it at runtime.